# Wlan connecting after page load

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to load a webpage in a web browser component in a windows form.

Before I load the page I run a batch file to connect to a selected Wlan connection.

The problem is the Wlan is getting connected after a certain delay and in this time the web browser loads the web page which does not load.

How do I add a delay in between these two events

```
pe.WaitForExit()

webBrowser1.Navigate("http://10.10.116.5:8090/httpclient.html")
```

Below is the DocumentCompleted event

```
Sub WebBrowser1DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        Do While webBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete

            MsgBox("Here3")
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("username").Item(0).SetAttribute("value",username)
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("password").Item(0).SetAttribute("value",password)

            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("logincaption").Focus()
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("logincaption").InvokeMember("click")
            MsgBox("logged in")
        Loop
    End Sub
```

Can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check the "state" of the batch file in a `BackgroundWorker` and load the page after the worker has completed.

```
Public Sub Start()
    Dim file As String = "path_and_name_of_file"
    'TODO: Execute batch "path_and_name_of_file".
    Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(file)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim path As String = CStr(e.Argument)
    Dim watch As New Stopwatch()
    Dim timedOut As Boolean = False

    watch.Start()

    Do

        Try
            Using stream As IO.Stream = New IO.FileStream(path, IO.FileMode.Open)
            End Using
            Exit Do
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        'Time out after 2 minutes.
        If (watch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes > 2) Then
            timedOut = True
            Exit Do
        Else
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500) '<- Give thread some rest.
        End If

    Loop

    watch.Stop()

    ''Uncomment this line if you will add a 3 second delay AFTER executed batch:
    'If (Not cancelled) Then
    '    Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    'End If

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    'TODO: Load page.
End Sub
```

**Edit**

Come to think of it, you could try to ping the ip-address:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim watch As New Stopwatch()
    Dim timedOut As Boolean = False

    watch.Start()

    Do

        Try
            If (My.Computer.Network.Ping("10.10.116.5", 100)) Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        'Time out after 2 minutes.
        If (watch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes > 2) Then
            timedOut = True
            Exit Do
        Else
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500) '<- Give thread some rest.
        End If

    Loop

    watch.Stop()

End Sub
```