# Want to load a webpage after connecting to wifi

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to load a webpage from a windows form application web browser control.

I first connect to a wifi network using a batch file which I run from the vb.net application

Now I want to load the webpage only after I connect to the wifi network.

But the wifi takes a little time to connect and the browser control pings the webpage before the wifi connects and throws an exception.

Can someone suggest how I solve this problem.

```
While My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable=True
                MsgBox("checking..")
                If My.Computer.Network.Ping("10.10.116.5",1000) Then
                    MsgBox("checking2..")
                    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://10.10.116.5:8090/httpclient.html")
                End If

            End While
```

Comment: Were the `BackgroundWorker` too scary? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024708/wlan-connecting-after-page-load

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Thread.Sleep` to pause the your app for some time like this :

```
Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

this will stop it for tow second then continue.

Comment: your app is Thread by it self this will pause the app for some time until wifi is connected then it will continue.